# How to run terminal as administrator to use virtualenv

Tags: python, powershell, windows-7, virtualenv, pycharm

In PyCharm I set my terminal to be the Windows PowerShell, but when I try to use virtualenv in that terminal:

```
Import-Module virtualenvwrapper
```

(I have this command in a startup script, but just included the command alone for simplicity)

I get the following error:

```
Import-Module : File C:\Users\Sean\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\virtualenvwrapper\support.psm1 cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please see "get-help about_signing" for more details.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  virtualenvwrapper
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

So I try to enable script execution (as I did for PowerShell *outside* of PyCharm):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

But get the following error (I avoided this error outside of PyCharm by running PowerShell as administrator):

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.
At line:1 char:20
+ Set-ExecutionPolicy <<<<  RemoteSigned
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-ExecutionPolicy], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

So what can I do to be able to use virtualenv from the PyCharm terminal?

- Windows 7
- Python 2.7
- PyCharm Community Edition 3.0

Comment: Have you tried running PyCharm as an admin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The permissions error you are getting is caused by Powershell not having administrative rights on the machine. The quick solution is to start up Powershell using [Run as Administrator](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token). From there, you can use [`Set-ExecutionPolicy`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx).

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

In addition, you might need to use the -Scope parameter when calling `Set-ExecutionPolicy`. Sometimes when running Powershell in a child process, the execution policy used is different than when running powershell independently.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way..  If you have the option to using [UAC - User Access Control](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/user-account-control) and you can lower down to allow execution of programs.  In a domain, this maybe set per GPO/LGPO.  Be careful when trying to over-ride these settings.